Can't navigate directly to specific pages in React .NET App
I have created a React app with .NET (created through Visual Studio), and when I run it locally all works fine. I have published the app to Azure App Service, and the home page works fine. However, when I navigate directly to a specific page (eg. https://url/some-page) I get a 404 Not Found error.
From my research, I know this is something to do with the server routing, but how can I configure the server to open the pages when you navigate directly to them?
From my program.cs
app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();            

if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseCors(CorsHelper.AllowAnyCorsPolicyName);

app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
});

vite.config.ts
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url';

import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import plugin from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';
import child_process from 'child_process';
import { env } from 'process';

const baseFolder =
    env.APPDATA !== undefined && env.APPDATA !== ''
        ? `${env.APPDATA}/ASP.NET/https`
        : `${env.HOME}/.aspnet/https`;

const certificateName = "webapp.client";
const certFilePath = path.join(baseFolder, `${certificateName}.pem`);
const keyFilePath = path.join(baseFolder, `${certificateName}.key`);

if (!fs.existsSync(certFilePath) || !fs.existsSync(keyFilePath)) {
    if (0 !== child_process.spawnSync('dotnet', [
        'dev-certs',
        'https',
        '--export-path',
        certFilePath,
        '--format',
        'Pem',
        '--no-password',
    ], { stdio: 'inherit', }).status) {
        throw new Error("Could not create certificate.");
    }
}

const target = env.ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT ? `https://localhost:${env.ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT}` :
    env.ASPNETCORE_URLS ? env.ASPNETCORE_URLS.split(';')[0] : 'https://localhost:7109';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [plugin()],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
        }
    },
    server: {
        proxy: {
            '^/weatherforecast': {
                target,
                secure: false
            }
        },
        port: 5173,
        https: {
            key: fs.readFileSync(keyFilePath),
            cert: fs.readFileSync(certFilePath),
        }
    }
})

Worth noting with this one, I have deleted the default WeatherForecastController, so not sure if that has something to do with it.

You have created the WebApp from Visual Studio ?

@Harshitha yeah through Visual Studio

Are you able to see the React default page when the app is loaded initially?

Yeah the app loads fine at the root, and when I navigate using the page links (using react-router) it works fine, it is just when I refresh on a non-root page, or navigate directly to it in the browser

First you need to load react app, which Has router that handles page router. When navigating directly, you dont load react, thus dont load react router, resulting in the request going to ASP.net app, which can not find react specific router, and returning 404. You need to add some custom middleware to handle such cases in your backend. Or point all traffic to react app instead, and host separately ASP net app

Your ASP.NET Core server is probably not correctly configured to serve the base HTML file of your application. It may be trying to find a specific static file instead, and since there is no such file, it returns the 404 Not Found error.
Try using this middleware to have your server fallback to serve the base HTML file if you try to access a non-existent route. Add it before app.Run(), so it's near the end of the middleware pipeline, within UseEndpoints:
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
    endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
}

It comes from the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.StaticFilesEndpointRouteBuilderExtensions class.

Thank you! I have just added an edit, as the MapFallbackToFile needs to be within the UseEndpoints middleware. Other than that, it solved my issue perfectly

No problem, glad I could help!
